# Summary statistics on out-of-memory file

Tags: r, fst, disk.frame

I have a csv file that's 120GB in size which is a set of numerical values grouped by categorical variables.

eg.

```
df<-as.data.frame(x=rbing(rep("BLO",100),rep("LR",100)), y=runif(200))
```

I would like to calculate some summary statistics using group_by(x) but my file doesn't fit into memory. What are my options? I've looked at tidyfst and {disk.frame} but I'm not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a csv file or fst

Comment: Yes but as it turns out I also have an fst file for good measure.

Comment: tidyfst allows [grouping by](https://github.com/hope-data-science/tidyfst), but from my experience, as soon as the data is loaded, it becomes slow.  Another option would be Microsoft R with RevoScaleR grouping

Comment: I'm not sure if you've already come across this, but https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/working-with-large-datasets.html#out-of-memory-strategies

Comment: @akrun Yes I was trying tidyfst out last night but I thought it was trying to actually load all the data into memory. So instead what I was doing was tidyfst::parse("fstFile.fst") -> ft but that won't let me use the group_by. Am I missing something? I'll look at RevoScaleR.

Comment: @HCAI the `parse_fst` is very fast, but that is it.  Once you load the data, it becomes slow.  If you have many columns and are using only a few, then load only those columns, with an index to track

Comment: I have used RevoScaleR in the past with file size similar to yours in a server and it is fast as well

Comment: Ahh that makes sense about tidyfst. It took a very long time to run the query that my session kept timing out. I thought it was reading in the data as the documentation isn't quite clear. I'm on a Mac so looks like RevoScaleR isn't available.